# itertools.repeat(object[, times]) How do I optionally set the times option at runtime?

Tags: python

I have a loop:

```
for x in itertools.repeat(1)
```

Depending on the cmd line parameters I need this to be infinite or `x` number of times.

So this

```
for x in itertools.repeat(1)
```

or this

```
for x in itertools.repeat(1, x)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: An `if` statement?

Comment: I'm surprised that `itertools.repeat(1, None)` is not equivalent to `itertools.repeat(1)`; I'm inclined to consider that a bug.

Comment: Hi yes I did try itertools.repeat(1, None) but didn't work... thanks

Comment: I agree, I wish this issue had gotten more attention on the python bug tracker (https://bugs.python.org/issue34169), it wasted 20 min of my time digging through source code today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools.repeat` returns an iterable, so you can do this:

```
import sys
import itertools

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    repeater = itertools.repeat(1, int(sys.argv[1]))
else:
    repeater = itertools.repeat(1)

for x in repeater:
    print x
```

`sys.argv` is the cli inputs; `argv[0]` will always be the script name, so I'm assuming `argv[1]` will be your input.

Comment: Haha, beat me by 39 s. Might need to explain to the asker what `sys.argv` is though.

Comment: This is what worked for me..I hoped something like itertools.repeat(1, None) but anyway... yes thanks also I knew what sys.argv was :)

Answer (score 0):

It's Python, so you can do this: if `myCondition` is the thing you want to test (e.g. `a == 2`), then:

```
myIterator = itertools.repeat(1) if myCondition else itertools.repeat(1, x)

for x in myIterator:
    do-something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `islice` instead of the second argument to limit the number
of items returned.

```
import argparse
import itertools

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("--count", type=int, default=None)
args = p.parse_args()

ones = itertools.repeat(1)
for x in itertools.islice(ones, args.count):
    ...
```

If the `stop` argument to `islice` is `None`, then there is no upper limit
on the number of items in the slice.

---

I'm surprised that `repeat` itself does
not accept `None` to explicitly trigger the default behavior. I submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue34169); we'll see if the maintainers consider it a bug as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick one-liner solution that's nice compact which I used, I wanted to repeat an infinite number of times or only once, you can use this:

```
itertools.repeat(my_object, *([] if my_condition else [1]))
```

The argument expansion won't happen for the `[]` case and thus you get the effect of `None` you would expect based on the documentation and (in my opinion) a reasonable reading of the functions purpose.

Otherwise `[1]` will expand to `times=1`, you could replace 1 with whatever value you wanted.

`times=None` would have been cleaner, but c'est las vie, the maintainers didn't want it (https://bugs.python.org/issue34169).